# Why isn't JayDeBeApi returning data?

Tags: python, sql, jdbc, hsqldb, jaydebeapi

I am trying to test JayDeBeApi by accessing a local HSQL database on my computer.  I have set up the database and I know there is data in it, but I am getting nothing when I run my code.

My table is called PA0101.ALERT_PRIORITY.  It has the following data.

PRIORITY_CD PRIORITY_DN
1   High
2   Medium
3   Low

Here is my code.

```
import jaydebeapi
import os

os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191'

conn = jaydebeapi.connect("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver",
                          "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb",
                          ["SA", "SA"],
                          "C:\\PATH\\hsqldb.jar")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM PA0101.ALERT_PRIORITY")
curs.fetchall()
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

I have tried putting inserts in the curs.execute statement, and gotten a "you don't have permission or object nott found" exception.

Fixed this.  Just needed to incase the curs.fetchall() in a print().

Comment: The error message indicates the database table does not exist. Connect to database with the HSQLDB DatabaseManager app (it is in the same jar) and check your datababase contents.

Comment: I have run the same query from the HSQL database manager and I get the expected results.  My Python program is not finding the table for some reason.  How can I check to see that my program sees the tables at all?

Comment: Fixed this.  Just needed to incase curs.fetchall() in print().